# Nested mysql transactions between 2 tables using sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, promise, sequelize.js

I have 2 sequelize models (Event and Inventory associated with 2 tables).  I created a Event._create method so that I can use it to create an event in event db with multiple products recorded in the inventory db at the same time.  Each inventory is associated with the event_id of the newly created event.

Because all these stuff should success or fail altogether, I use sequelize's transaction to achieve this.

Initially I was thinking about doing something like this.

```
sequelize.transactionPromise = Promise.promisify(sequelize.transaction, sequelize);

return sequelize.transactionPromise({autocommit: 0})
.then(function(t) {
    return Event.create(ev, {transaction: t})
    .then(function(event){
        var event_id = event.id;  // ------ (*)
        return Promise.resolve([1, ..., event_number])
        .then(function(){
            Inventory.create({product_id: some_product_id, event_id: event_id}, 
            {transaction: t});
        });
    .then(function(){ 
        return Promise.cast(t.commit())
        .then(function() { // successfully committed  
            return res.json(d);
        }).catch(function(err){ // cannot commit somehow
            return res.json(500, err.toString());
        });
    }).catch(function(err){  // error rollback
        return Promise.cast(t.rollback())
        .then(function() {
            return Promise.reject('rollback: ' + err.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work because before the transaction is commiteed the (*) has no value and gives me event_id of NULL.

Instead I do something like below:

```
var Event = sequelize.model('Event'); 
var Inventory = sequelize.model('Inventory');

var _create = function(t, ev){
    var ev_id_secret = {secret: 'some random secret'};
    return Promise.cast(Event.create(ev_id_secret))
    .then(function(d){
        ev_id_secret.id = d.id;
        return true;
    }).then(function(){
        return Promise.resolve(_.range(ev.number_of_products))
        .map(function(){
            var inventory = {
                event_id: ev_id_secret.id,
                product_id: ev.product_id
            };
            return Promise.cast(Inventory._create(t, inventory));
        });
    }).then(function(){  // thennable a transaction
            return Promise.cast(Event.update(ev, ev_id_secret, {transaction: t}));
    });
};
```

So I can do something like this.

```
sequelize.transactionPromise=Promise.promisify(sequelize.transaction, sequelize); 
return sequelize.transactionPromise({autocommit: 0})
.then(function(t) {
    return Event._create(t, ev)
    .then(function(){
        return Promise.cast(t.commit())
        .then(function() {
            return res.json(d);
        }).catch(function(err){
            return res.json(500, err.toString());
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        return Promise.cast(t.rollback())
        .then(function() {
            return Promise.reject('rollback: ' + err.toString());
        });
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err.stack);
    res.json(500, {error: err.toString()});
});
```

What I do with _create is that I just insert an empty event (with randomly generated secret) in Event db and some empty products in Inventory db, later get event_id using this secret to query, update the event and the inventory accordingly.

The thing is when the promise is rejected, the transaction rollback() is called and leave empty event and product records in the db.  So I have to deal with the empty records later, which is really disturbing.

So my question is how do I do transaction between 2 tables correctly?  Am I on the right track?

p.s: as a side question you can see my code is full of return Promise.xxx statements, this ensures the control flow but the promise gets really messy.  Is there something I can do to improve my code?  Thanks.

Comment: Which promise library are you using? ALso, could you post all of your code, including the outer promise wrapper?

Comment: promise is bluebird.js. mysql ORM is sequelize.js

Answer (score 3):

Your original implementation was correct. However, after you created the event, the object should come back with the id already populated without having to commit (I'm assuming you're using the standard auto-incremented sequelize id's). All SQL databases function this way. I recommend debugging your application as to determine the root of the problem.

Here's a sample implementation of sequelize transaction from one of my applications. I've just tested and confirmed that calling db.Deposit.create() resolves to an object with valid id. I am using Bluebird, Sequelize 2.0.0-rc2, and Postgresql 9.3

```
module.exports.createDeposit = function(deposit) {
  return db.sequelize.transaction({isolationLevel: 'READ COMMITTED' })
  .then(function(t){
    var strQuery = 'UPDATE "Accounts" '
                   + 'SET "balance"="balance" + :amount, "updatedAt"=NOW() '
                   + 'WHERE "id"= :AccountId RETURNING *';

    return sql.query(strQuery,
                     db.Account.build(),
                     { raw: true, transaction : t },
                     { AccountId: deposit.AccountId, amount: deposit.amount })

    .then(function(account){
      if (!account) throw new Error('Account does not exist')
      return db.Deposit.create(deposit, { transaction: t });
    })
    .then(function(dbDeposit){
      // If successful, dbDeposit object contains a valid id
      if (!dbDeposit) throw new Error('Failed to create deposit');
      return t.commit()
      .then(function(){
        return dbDeposit;
      });
    })
    .catch(function(e){
      return t.rollback()
      .then(function(){
        throw e;
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: yes I researched a little and indeed the .create gives me something with an id. But am I guaranteed that I won't run into race conditions?

Comment: You can't run into a race condition with .create(). When you call .create, sequelize issues an insert command which increments the serial id key, hence the id assigned to that object is atomic.  Even if you abort the transaction with a rollback, no other object can ever be assigned that id, it is part of how SQL databases work.

Comment: if I want to create a record, and immediately update it in the same transaction. Can this work?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. For instance you can create a record, update some other record in another table, and then update the first record you created, all in the same transaction.

Comment: let me test it again.

Answer (score 2):

Your original implementation was correct as far as i can tell but can be improved by levering managed transactions and full promise support in the latest versions of Sequelize:

```
return sequelize.transaction({autocommit: false}, function(t) {
  return Event.create(ev, {transaction: t}).then(function(event) {
    return Promise.map(_.range(event_number), function (number) {
      return Inventory.create({product_id: some_product_id, event_id: event.get('id')}, {transaction: t});
    });
  });
}).then(function(){
  // Automatically comitted at this point if the promise chain returned to the transaction successfully resolved
  return res.status(200).json(d);
}).catch(function(err){
  // Automatically rolledback at this point if the promise chain returned to the transaction was rejected
  return res.status(403).json();
});
```

You can read more about managed transactions on the docs: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/transactions/

Comment: Doesn't get any more official than this :) I'm glad you're enjoying the transaction syntax.

Comment: my version is also "version": "2.0.0-rc2", but without t.commit() the sql statements still won't get commited somehow..

Comment: It was introduced in 2.0.0-rc1. Are you still using `.then()` or have you implemented my vode?